# Is adding a Microsoft 365 group inside a SharePoint group supported?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365-groups

I have a modern SharePoint site - this site is connected to **M365 group A**.

I want to share one folder in this site with **M365 group B Members**.

So the question is - Is it supported?

Answer (score 1):

Ofc, it is supported in SharePoint Online.

You could share the folder to another group via the icon.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can share a folder with a Microsoft 365 group. But with some caveats. You can only do it via the "**Sharing link**".

[image]

When using the Sharing link, you are breaking inheritance for your folder. Just bear it in mind.
[image]

While sharing via the link seems to work, you **can't** share a folder with an M365 group via the **classic** "permissions" page (see screenshot below). Unfortunately M365 groups don't show up in the people picker. This is because SharePoint only recognizes Security AD groups, but not M365 groups.

[image]